# issue with creating a new line in hyperterminal

Tags: microcontroller

I am sending few data to the hyperterminal via UART. When i send a new line character, the data moves to the next line but it starts from the point where the previous data is stopped. The cursor doesn't move to the beginning of the line.I have tried many times using ASCII 10,11 and 13 and it still doesn't work.How do i fix this?

Comment: ASCII 13 (0x0A) should return to the start of the line, are you certain you sent it?

Comment: @Jasen 13 != 10

Comment: HA! I meant 0x0D

Comment: Some terminal emulators have configuration options to allow different newline sequences. If Hyperterminal doesn't, one answer is to upgrade to one (e.g. PuTTY) that does.

Comment: you are sending 0x0A but not 0x0D. if this is a printf try /r/n instead of just /n

Comment: I just sigin to thanks those answer! by default when press Enter key hyperterminal will send \r(0X0D)
if wanna send 0x0d 0x0a(\r\n) press Enter key and Ctrl+j
or setting in Hyperterm like first floor answer

Answer (score 5):

Hyperterminal has not been included in Windows since pre-Win7 so it's pretty much deprecated. Most of us use some alternative(s) such as Putty, Realterm or Teraterm (all free downloads).

**CR LF**  (in that order!) should do it (0x0D, 0x0A), but there is a setting in Hyperterm that allows you to automatically tack a **LF** on the end of a **CR**.

[image]

Other terminal programs will typically have a similar option- here is Realterm:

[image]

Comment: +1 for screencapturing Hyperterminal, and drawing arrows. Helps a bunch, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Generally CR/LF should do the job.

CR is carriage return, with cursor going to the beginning of the same line.

LF is line feed, with cursor moving next line vertically (this is what you currently see on your terminal).

Send two characters one after another - 0x0d (13) and 0x0a (10).

Some applications will consider only LF to be new line indicator, but these applications are oriented for data flow rather than displaying this data on simple text devices like ASCII terminal.